# Unable to resize widgets inside appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, containers, appbar

The size of my container is not changing when I am using it inside App bar. I tried wrapping it inside a sizedBox even then it's not working as expected. And not only container , I am unable to resize any of the buttons inside appbar.

Comment: Could you share the code which is NOT working?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply **Transform** or **Icon** Widget in Flutter to fix this issue.

- Wrapping as a child widget (Container, IconButton...) inside Transform.scale().
- Scale of the Icon widget can be easily adjusted by using its size property.

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              leading: Transform.scale(
                scale: 0.5,  // effect to size of child widget
                child: Container(
                  width: 5,
                  height: 5,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ),
              title: Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.7,  // effect to size of child widget
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/back_button.svg"),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.person_off_outlined,
                  size: 32,  // effect to size of Icon widget
                ),
              ]),
          body: Container(),
        );
      }
```

[Result Mobile view of 'Appbar'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2mJX.png)